# "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately" on blocking method

Tags: c#, sockets

I’m using C# Socket in synchronized mode (I mean that the socking is blocking and I’m using “Send” and not BeginSend)
I sometimes get “A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately” after sending data
In addition I'm receiving the data using BeginReceive

Does anyone know why I'm getting this exception and what does it mean?

Comment: At what point are you getting the exception? BeginReceive is an asynchronous operation.